# How do I copy an element's events with its innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I incorporated a simple lightbox functionality into my webapp:

```
for(var i = 0, l = figs.length; i<l; i++){
    figs[i].addEventListener("dblclick",function(){
        lightbox.style.display = "block";
        lbox.innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
    });
}
```

The problem is that I want the interactivity of the div to copy into the lightbox (these are graphs that each have event listeners that make them interactive). Is there any way that I can accomplish this less storing all of the events inside an array and somehow copying those?

Comment: *"How do I copy an element's events with its innerHTML?"* You can't. Why don't you [clone the DOM node instead](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.cloneNode)?

Comment: perfect! are there any limits to this? how is browser support for that?

Comment: You can check the MDN documentation ;) (it should be supported by all browsers).

Comment: actually that won't work: "Cloning a node copies all of its attributes and their values, including intrinsic (in–line) listeners. It does not copy event listeners added using addEventListener()"

Comment: Oh... guess I expected too much :-/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you are using `jQuery` you will not be able to clone a node with all it's event handlers and even if you could it's usually not a good idea (I could expand if you need to).

I suppose that these listeners were attached through some processes targetting these DOM nodes (e.g. applying a plugin). What you should be doing is simply do a deep or shallow copy of the DOM elements you want using `Element.prototype.cloneNode` and re-execute those processes against the clones.

If the cloning process is complex you might consider encapsulating it within the *class* which is adding the listeners. Something like:

```
function SomeObj(el) {
    this.el = el;
    attachSomeHandlersToEl();
}

SomeObj.prototype.clone = function () {
    var newEl = this.el.cloneNode(true);

    return new this.constructor(newEl);
};

var el = document.getElementById('some-el'),
    someObj = new SomeObj(el),
    clonedEl = someObj.clone().el;
```